# How to generate power spectra of AR-1 process in matlab?

Tags: matlab, time-series, vector-auto-regression

I have a time series x1 as 3600x1 double. I need to fit AR-1 spectra on the power spectral density of x1. Well, I am not an expert and this is the first time I am studying time series.

If AR-1 process is given as: X(t)=alpha1*X(t-1)+z(t)
So far I have calculated variance of time series, variance of noise (z(t)) and the value of alpha1. However, I am unable to find a function in Matlab which can plot spectra of AR-1.

I tried ar(),pyulear(),psd(),freqz,lpc etc functions. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK7fG.jpg)

smoothened plot - AR-1 process spectra ,
skewed plot- spectra of time series

Comment: yes freqz is the one I think (you can also plot directly $H(e^{it})$ with $H(z) = 1-\alpha z^{-1} $...  and lpc is for estimating directly $\alpha$ from the time series

Comment: freqz(1,[1,a]);

Comment: (of course everyone understood that I meant $\displaystyle H(z) = \frac{1}{1-a z^{-1}}$ ...)

Comment: thank a lot. I calculated alpha and variance from aryule(). Both aryule and lpc give same results. However, I need to plot the spectra. Please see the figure. It does not fit well with the power spectra of time series.

Comment: it does fit not so bad, if you compute an AR-k model with k=2,3 or 4 it should be better (if it doesn't, it means that you didn't plot well), and with lpc you can estimate $a$ and $b$ in $\sum_k a_k X(t-k) \approx \sum_m b_m z(t-m)$ (it's also called and AR-MA (for moving average) model) and plot the obtained coefs with freqz

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. I think I am getting a little bit now.